# python pass variable through os.system

Tags: python

This gets the latest mp3 file in my Directory

```
new_file = [(os.path.getmtime(ft) , os.path.basename(ft))
            for ft in os.listdir(path) if ft.lower().endswith('.mp3')]

new_file.sort()
```

Assigning the latest file to the file I am going to play

```
playFile = new_file[0][1]
```

Getting the Directory for the file.

```
PlayfileDir = os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(playFile)
```

Playing the file. This is where I get the error 'PlayfileDir' cannot be found.

```
os.system('start "PlayfileDir"')
```

Comment: Don't use `os.system`; use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: Your file path is wrong. The file is located in `path`, not in `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: But there are many things wrong here. In all the other calls, to build up the command using string concatenation. Why don't you do that in the last one as well?

Comment: Don't you means `os.system('start \'{}\''.format(PlayfileDir))`? And btw - please - don't use camelcase, snakecase ftw!

Comment: @Arount: this being Windoze, those single quotes around the directory name should be double quotes.

Comment: poor windows guys.. well thanks for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since `PlayfileDir` is a variable that is a `string`, you can just concatenate it to `'start'` (as pointed out by `@cdarke`, you need to also add the quotes!). As you have it at the moment, you are trying to start the actual string `'PlayfileDir'`, not the string in the variable.

So, you should do something like:

```
os.system('start "' + PlayfileDir + '"')
```

Comment: Note that the `PlayfileDir` variable already has a string. No need for the cast.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yep

Comment: @cdarke Thanks! Am on Linux, so couldn't test this but definitely key!

Comment: @JoeIddon: would apply to Linux as well, although no one in their right mind would have a directory name which includes whitespace :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to start using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib)!

```
from pathlib import Path

p = input("Gimme a path: ")

newest_mp3 = sorted(Path(p).glob('*.mp3'), reverse=True, key=lambda p: p.stat().st_mtime)[0]

os.system('start "{}"'.format(newest_mp3))
```

Comment: Hi this works well but it opens a command window in which i have to type the file name to play it. Is there a way to do this automatically

Comment: Instead of doing `os.system(...)`, do a `print(...)` and see what is being generated.